# Percentage Of Different Scales That Are Exactly Alike?

Tags: theory, scales

Was playing with iOS app “Piano Companion” and apparently I'm really quite amazingly consistent.

[image: myfavz]

I added two favorite scales that I found in the app and they are exactly the same; namely:

> D#/Eflat Yu

and

> D#/Eflat Dorian

Which got me thinking:

- What Percentage Of Different Scales Are Exactly Alike?

Comment: I don't see, how a percentage would help in anyway. A percentage is  only meaningful, if you define from which set. I for one never encountered something like Yu nor does wikipedia deliver any hits beyond chinese *instruments*.

Comment: @guidot just curiosity, what's the likelyhood two scales would be exactly the same, that's all...

Comment: The thing is, there isn't an exhaustive list of scales (you can even create new ones yourself). Also, many existing scales don't have established names. That makes it impossible to answer this question in its current state.

Comment: If you're interested in this kind of thing, you should try reading up on music theory. Start by googling the "circle of fifths", and looking into what differentiates different types of scales (major vs minor is a good starting point). It'll help you learn why this is the wrong question to ask, and in fact makes very little sense to an experienced musician.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of them. Here's the simple reason why. We use different systems to name, describe, and label scales. Let's just look at the C major scale to start.

The C major scale can also be referred to as the C Ionian mode when thinking in modal contexts, but there are more ways to describe the scale then just that. You can describe a scale by pattern i.e. the C major scales has the pattern WWHWWWH starting on C. Yet another way to describe it is by its pitch class sets which for the C major scale would be {0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11}.

As other's have pointed out, not every singe scale has an official name, but you can describe every scale based on it's pattern or pitch class set so just by default there are two different systems to identify a scale.

Answer (score 0):

Probably more than you want to know:

Johnson, Timothy (2003), Foundations of Diatonic Theory: A Mathematically Based Approach to Music Fundamentals, Key College Publishing. ISBN 1-930190-80-8.

:)